# Converting GeoTIFF into KMZ image using GDAL_translate returns empty, all black image

Tags: geotiff-tiff, ubuntu, gdal-translate, kmz

### GDAL

I have installed gdal in the following way:
`conda create -c conda-forge -n mygdalenv gdal python=3.6`
on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

### Input GeoTIFF

I have a GeoTiff image. The result of `gdalinfo input.tif` is:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: input.tif
Size is 10455, 13254
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (41.462915653613621,37.384259792199842)
Pixel Size = (0.000125314982135,-0.000125314982135)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=input
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  41.4629157,  37.3842598) ( 41d27'46.50"E, 37d23' 3.34"N)
Lower Left  (  41.4629157,  35.7233350) ( 41d27'46.50"E, 35d43'24.01"N)
Upper Right (  42.7730838,  37.3842598) ( 42d46'23.10"E, 37d23' 3.34"N)
Lower Right (  42.7730838,  35.7233350) ( 42d46'23.10"E, 35d43'24.01"N)
Center      (  42.1179997,  36.5537974) ( 42d 7' 4.80"E, 36d33'13.67"N)
Band 1 Block=10455x13254 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

### Conversion to KMZ

I then try to convert it into a KMZ, in the following way:
`gdal_translate -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY input.tif output.kmz`

### Issue

The conversion is super fast (too fast I would say) and always results in a 4.5MB file, while the input is 500MB.
When I visualize the KMZ file in Google Earth Pro (simple drag and drop), the image is correctly located, but is just a black rectangle.

Any help on what step I am doing wrong/forgetting?

Comment: Your source image seems to be of Type=Float32. Try with `gdal_translate -scale -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY input.tif output.kmz` but I agree that the small file size is suspicious.

Comment: Thanks @user30184! It solved my issue.  
I just need to figure out why `-a_nodata 0` doesn't remove black borders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the comments, namely adding `-scale`.

The full command is:
`gdal_translate -scale -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY input.tif output.kmz`